# What is validation set for yolov5 training and is it necessary?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, training-data, yolov5

I'm training a yolov5 model and I have a dataset but I couldn't understand the differences between validation and test data. Should I split my dataset to train/test/val or just train/test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **validation dataset** provides an unbiased assessment of a fitted model on the training dataset while fitting the model's hyper-parameters (e.g. the number of hidden units - layers and layer widths - in a neural network). Validation datasets can be used for early stop regularization (stopping training when the error in the validation dataset increases, as this is a sign of overfitting to the training dataset)

Comment: So, should I split my dataset into train/test/val because I don't want to decrease the size of the train data and what do you suggest about the percentages (like %80 train - %10 test - %10 val etc.)?

Comment: It depends on the amount of the dataset you have.

Comment: I have 1529 images and more than 8000 instances for only 1 class. Is it possible to detect overfitting without using validation set?

Comment: Sounds low samples. Maybe  these sorts of ratios are
 reasonable. However,  in the previous era of machine learning, it was common practice to take all your data and
split it according to maybe a 70/30%.

Comment: SO, since you have a relatively small dataset, these traditional ratios might be okay.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was wrong. I have 2396 images and more than 13000 instances for 1 class. Are you telling that 30% for test or val data?

Comment: do you mean 1300 instances (with two zeros)?

Comment: Nope. As I said, I have 2396 images and in these images, there are more than 13.000 instances as total.

Comment: Remember, there is no specific number in setting up train, dev and test sets. In this case the training  might work better in between 65 to 75%.

Comment: So, should I split to train/test/val or train/test? What are the differences between test and validation sets?

Comment: In practice, it is a highly iterative process. you often start with an idea and then you just have to code it up and see how it is performing.

Comment: I got your point but still I don't event know the differences between test and val sets

Comment: Validation set is to see which of many different models performs best and then you will choose the best performing model and apply it to test set(never seen data)

Comment: I'm gonna train the model with train set and test it with test set while training. (It means there is nothing to do with validation set while training) After training, I will choose the best trained model with val.py file and also i need a validation set for that. Is it right?

Comment: No, the goal of the val set is that you're going
to test different algorithms on it and see which algorithm works better. The test set is not used in training.

Comment: Check out this one. `https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/validation/another-partition`

Comment: You need test set to evaluate the final model (best model).

Comment: Thank you for your help! Actually, i have an algorithm and bunch of videos which I can test the model and compare with others. As a result, i think i don't want to lose hundreads of images just for checking whether the model is overfitted because I already can detect this by using the model on my algorithm.

Comment: Awesome, keep learning and see which works best for you.