# YOLOv5: does best.pt control for overfitting?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, yolov5, fitness

After each YOLOv5 training, two model files are saved: `last.pt` and `best.pt`. I'm aware that:

- `last.pt` is the latest saved checkpoint of the model. This will be updated after each epoch.
- `best.pt` is the checkpoint that has the best validation loss so far. It is updated whenever the model fitness improves.

Fitness is defined as a weighted combination of `mAP@0.5` and `mAP@0.5:0.95` metrics:

```py
 def fitness(x): 
     # Returns fitness (for use with results.txt or evolve.txt) 
     w = [0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.9]  # weights for [P, R, mAP@0.5, mAP@0.5:0.95] 
     return (x[:, :4] * w).sum(1)
```

My question is, if the training continued for too many epochs (and `last.pt` is thus overfitted), is `best.pt` then a checkpoint from when the training was not yet overfit? In other words, does `best.pt` control for overfitting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can assume that the `best.pt` has a good performance for non-training data when the model has a regularization. However, I saw some researchers who choose a model which doesn't have the best result in terms of the limitation of validation loss.

If you don't have a lot of costs to train your model, you could consider the option that I mentioned, otherwise, you could just pick up the `best.pt`.

In addition, we choose some of the models to ensemble them. This can collaborate with the first, second, etc., Although the validation loss of models has a slight difference, they can produce better performance than just using the best model.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. So for models **without** regularization, `best.pt` **does not** control for overfitting, but for models **with** regularization, it **does**? Also, if you're training a model using the standard yolov5 method  (`python train.py --data coco128.yaml --weights yolov5s.pt`), does it have a regularization?

Comment: Normally, in the Segmentation problem, people use some approach to prevent their model from overfitting dataset by doing Cross Validation. Also, people add some layers of BN(Batch Normalization), which can normalize data while passing. In Yolo case, I cannot directly support your situation, though, there is some reference, which could help you. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71102661/what-is-validation-set-for-yolov5-training-and-is-it-necessary`

Comment: In addition, I'm sure that the `best.pt` cannot be a result of the best in the training if the model encounters new data. Nevertheless, it can be best If you are not collecting new data then feeding the model. Note that the result could be different if you change the ratio of validation and training set or they are shuffled. Therefore it depends on many situation, which could be controlled.